# Julia ccall: could not find function in library

Tags: c, julia, shared-libraries

I am trying to use ccall to call functions from a shared library I created.
Currently, when I try to run ccall, I get an error:

```
ERROR: ccall: could not find function add in library libbar
 in anonymous at no file
 in include at boot.jl:244
 in include_from_node1 at loading.jl:128
 in process_options at client.jl:282
 in _start at client.jl:351
while loading /somedir/juliatest.jl, in expression starting on line 2
```

However, when I view the contents of libbar.so, the function is listed:

...
000000000000057c T add(float, float)
...

Here is my setup:

```
// bar.hpp
#ifndef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern float add(float a, float b);

#ifndef __cplusplus
}
#endif

// bar.cpp
#include "bar.hpp"
float add(float a, float b)
{
return a+b;
}
```

Here is how I compile it:

```
g++ -Wall -fPIC -c bar.cpp
gcc -shared -o libbar.so -Wl,-soname,libbar.so.1 -o libbar.so.1.0 bar.o
sudo mv libbar.so.1.0 /opt/lib
sudo ln -sf /opt/lib/libbar.so.1.0 /opt/lib/libbar.so.1
sudo ln -sf /opt/lib/libbar.so.1.0 /opt/lib/libbar.so
```

Here is my julia script:

```
println("Running Test Function")
shouldBeThree = ccall( (:add, "libbar"), Float32, (Float32, Float32), 1.0, 2.0)
println("Should be Three: ", shouldBeThree)
```

Comment: I think it is strange that nm lists the function with arguments. Doesn't that indicate that the name is mangled and the ``extern "C"`` is somehow not triggering?

Comment: Hmmm. If I look at bar.o the function does appear to be mangled. That means I have to fix how I compile it?

Comment: Then you have to give Julia the mangled name, or figure out what is happening. Do you need the ``extern`` keyword at the same line as the function prototype? I'm not a guru, but I have never seen a function declared extern that way before.

Comment: Solved by suggestion from ivarne. C++ was mangling the function name.

I changed bar.hpp, removing the #ifndef stuff

    // bar.hpp
    extern "C" float add(float a, float b);

And now it runs correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are compiling with `g++`. Therefore `__cplusplus` is defined, and your `extern "C"` is excluded by the preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use `#ifndef` instead of `#ifdef` in the header file.

```
// bar.hpp
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

float add(float a, float b);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

With that change the file should compile with both C and C++ compilers.